# Decompiling MCP gives error ("Initial client recompile failed")

Tags: java, minecraft

I've been trying to decompile MCP for some time now. After reinstalling Minecraft and MCP 1.12 and running `decompile.bat`, MCP has produced this error:

```
Initial client recompile failed, correct source then run updatemd5
```

I haven't changed the Minecraft source *at all*, and after reinstalling Minecraft and MCP, I still get the same output of 15 errors during recompilation.

I am using Java 10.0.1 and the corresponding JDK.

Comment: You shouldn't be using MCP directly, you should be using Forge or Bukkit (or whatever replaced Bukkit, I can't keep track).

Comment: You should be using java 8. Modded minecraft does not fully support java 9+.

Comment: @killjoy I know I'm almost 2 years late but I was recently decompiling MCP again and this worked